# Angular - Dynamic stylesheet rendering based on a query parameter in url

Tags: angular, user-interface, templates, dynamic, webpack

I have a requirement where i need to render the styles for application based on a query parameter in url.

```
https://<domainName>.com/?theme=xyz
```

After going through various articles i am confused if ***ng-href*** will be useful for my requirement.

Also in prod build i need to have the hash in respective css file names. Should i include all the css files in webpack and use **--output-hashing=all**?
How should i scale the approach when i have 20-30 themes.

output should be something like

```
xyz.style.**027b05e9f06e48912b48**.bundle.css
```

where xyz is picked from the query parameter. And this should be embedded in html dynamically.

Can someone help me on how to approach this requirement.